# How to optimize merging only on lines matching a condition?

Tags: pandas, optimization, merge

I want to left merge df_1 and df_2 on column `a`

I can archive it easily with:

`df_3 = df_1.merge(df_2, on="a", how="left")`

However, I know I will never find `a` in `df_2` when `df_1.b == 0`

So to optimze my code, I would like to merge df_1 with df_2 only when `df_1.b != 0`

How can I get df_3 more efficiently knowing this information ?

## input

```
d = {'a': list('ABCDEF'),                                                                           
     'b': list('111000')}                                                                           
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)                                                                         
                                                                                                    
#    a  b                                                                                           
# 0  A  1                                                                                           
# 1  B  1                                                                                           
# 2  C  1                                                                                           
# 3  D  0                                                                                           
# 4  E  0                                                                                           
# 5  F  0                                                                                           
                                                                                                    
d = {'a': list('ABC'),                                                                              
     'c': list('xyz')}                                                                              
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)                                                                         
                                                                                                    
#    a  c                                                                                           
# 0  A  x                                                                                           
# 1  B  y                                                                                           
# 2  C  z
```

## expected output

```
df_3                                                                                                
                                                                                                    
#    a  b    c                                                                                      
# 0  A  1    x                                                                                      
# 1  B  1    y                                                                                      
# 2  C  1    z                                                                                      
# 3  D  0  NaN                                                                                      
# 4  E  0  NaN                                                                                      
# 5  F  0  NaN
```

Comment: `merge` is already doing this check internally, you probably won't gain much performance by pre-filtering

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
m = df_1.b != '0'
df_3 = (df_1[m].reset_index().merge(df_2, on="a", how="left",
                                   suffixes=('','_'))
               .drop(df_1.columns, axis=1)
               .set_index('index'))

print (df_3)
       c
index   
0      x
1      y
2      z

out = pd.concat([df_1, df_3], axis=1)
print (out)
   a  b    c
0  A  1    x
1  B  1    y
2  C  1    z
3  D  0  NaN
4  E  0  NaN
5  F  0  NaN
```

Comment: Not exactly, imagine df_1 is 100 millions lines and for 10k lines (when b != 0) I need an additional information I could fine in df_2.

I don't want to apply my merge on all df_1 lines (not efficient) but only on the 10k lines

Comment: @Alexandre_K - Problem is left join in `merge` is fast, here is solution for create new added columns to `df_1` and append in `concat`. Answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

just merge it

```
df_1.merge(df_2, how = 'outer', on = 'a')
```